# Terraform referenced module has no attributes error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to use a Palo Alto Networks module to deploy a panorama VM instance to GCP with Terraform. In the example module, I see they create a VPC together with a subnetwork, however, I have an existing VPC I am adding to. So I data source the VPC and create the subnetwork with a module. Upon referencing this subnetwork in my VM instance module, it complains it has no attributes:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../../../modules/panorama/main.tf line 67, in resource "google_compute_instance" "panorama":
  67:     subnetwork = var.subnet
    |----------------
    | var.subnet is object with no attributes
```

Here is the subnet code:

```
  data "google_compute_network" "panorama" {
  project = var.project_id
  name    = "fed-il4-p-net-panorama"
}

module "panorama_subnet" {
  source = "../../../../modules/subnetwork-module"
  subnet_name = "panorama-${var.region_short_name[var.region]}"
  subnet_ip = var.panorama_subnet
  subnet_region = var.region
  project_id = var.project_id
  network = data.google_compute_network.panorama.self_link
}
```

Here is the panorama VM instance code:

```
module "panorama" {
  source = "../../../../modules/panorama"

  name = "${var.project_id}-panorama-${var.region_short_name[var.region]}"
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  zone = data.google_compute_zones.zones.names[0]
  *# panorama_version  = var.panorama_version
  ssh_keys = (file(var.ssh_keys))
  network = data.google_compute_network.panorama.self_link
  subnet = module.panorama                <====== I cannot do module.panorama.id or .name here
  private_static_ip = var.private_static_ip
  custom_image = var.custom_image_pano
  #attach_public_ip  = var.attach_public_ip
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

parent module for vm instance

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "panorama" {
  name                      = var.name
  zone                      = var.zone
  machine_type              = var.machine_type
  min_cpu_platform          = var.min_cpu_platform
  labels                    = var.labels
  tags                      = var.tags
  project                   = var.project
  can_ip_forward            = false
  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  metadata = merge({
    serial-port-enable = true
    ssh-keys           = var.ssh_keys
  }, var.metadata)

  network_interface {
/*
    dynamic "access_config" {
      for_each = var.attach_public_ip ? [""] : []
      content {
        nat_ip = google_compute_address.public[0].address
      }
    }
*/
    network_ip = google_compute_address.private.address
    network = var.network
    subnetwork = var.subnet
  }
```

Comment: This is wrong: `subnet = module.panorama`. Where should the value for the `subnet` variable come from? Also, please add more information, e.g., are the module calls in the same root module, are you using nested modules?

Comment: Hi Marko,

this is coming from a parent module. I've edited the question to include the parent module for the VM instance at the bottom. In the past I have been able to reference attributes of subnetworks like so:
module.subnetwork-external.vpc_subnetwork["external"]

Comment: Well you are not doing that at the moment, what changed?

Comment: I think there is a mistake on `subnet = module.panorama`, it's not `panorama_subnet` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue `var.xxx is object with [n] attributes` multiple times, and 9/10 times it has got to do with wrong referencing of a variable. In your case, in the `panorama VM module` , you're assigning value of subnet as:

> subnet = module.panorama

Now, its not possible to assign a module to an attribute within the module. From your problem statement, i see you're trying to get name attribute assigned to `subnet`. Try this:

> subnet = this.id OR
> subnet = this.name

Also, regarding what values can be called, the resources defined in a module are encapsulated, so the calling module cannot access their attributes directly. However, the child module can declare output values to selectively export certain values to be accessed by the calling module.

For example, if the ./panorama module referenced in the example below exported an output value named `subnet`

```
module "panorama" {
  source = "../../../../modules/panorama"
```

```
output "subnet_name" {
  value = var.subnet
}
```

OR WITHOUT SETTING `subnet` VALUE

```
output "subnet_name" {
  value = var.name
}
```

then the calling module can reference that result using the expression `module.panorama.outputs.subnet_name`. Hope this helps